# Chart.js (line chart) tooltip duration/delay

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

There does not seem to be any option or implementation on showing the tooltip for a second or two before it dissapears when going from a hovering to non-hovering state. So when you have your mouse hovering over the tooltip, great, it shows but then when you remove your mouse from the point I would like to have that showing for an extra 2 seconds instead of dissapearing instantly as it does currently.

*What I've done so far*

- I've looked through the documentation and the available tooltip options. It has a customTooltip function available but that is for when you want to implement a completely custom tooltip.
- Gone through the chart.js line chart's codebase where it attaches the events and can't seem to figure out how to add in a delay.
- Seen the 'mouseout', 'mouseover' events array list of strings but can't seem to figure out how to use them.

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I need to do on implementing this delay/fade effect on the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tooltips are cleared by the showTooltip function (the redraw clears off the existing tooltips). So one naïve way would be to hook into this to introduce your delay, like so

```
var data = {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [
        {
            data: [12, 23, 23, 43, 45, 12, 33]
        }
    ]
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data);

var originalShowTooltip = myLineChart.showTooltip;
var timeout;
myLineChart.showTooltip = function (activeElements) {
    var delay = (activeElements.length === 0) ? 2000 : 0;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        originalShowTooltip.call(myLineChart, activeElements);
    }, delay);
}
```

This delays the tooltips if the chart is going to clear off all tooltips.

Notice that there is no delay in removing the old tooltip if you move on to another tooltip. If you want it this to be a delayed disappearance, you'll need to maintain your own array of active points pushing in elements (instantaneously) / popping out elements (with a delay)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zubynd0c/